Who [has or have] access?
The following question is related but does not answer my question:
"Has" or "Have" after "Who" in a sentence?
'Who has access to data?' or 'Who have access to data?'
Note that there is nobody before 'Who' because it's a question.
Which one of these is correct, and most importantly, why?
edit:
The question (and its answers none of which accepted) that were suggested as "duplicate" do not answer my question:
Verb agreement with "who" in a question

"They were being rude." She said. I went to ask her, "Who was being
rude?"

This quote is from the question which uses the word They so it's really easy to answer the question.
My question however makes no such use or assumption as 'They', 'I', 'We' etc. to be able to know who is being referred to.
Further the quote from proposed duplicate is not a question but something else, it's a question with an indirect answer in it.
So please unmark my question as duplicate.

The question is certainly a duplicate of Verb agreement with 'who' in a question and should remain shut. // Note that the  distributive singular / plural can come into play, and "They were being rude," she said. I went to ask her "Who was being rude?" is correct if it is known that singular 'they' is being used and 'she' is being interrogated by say the police. // With your sentence, both are grammatical, but not identical.

@EdwinAshworth is correct if it is known that singular 'they' is being used and 'she' is being interrogated by say the police No such thing is known in my question, if you don't agree then please tell is it Who have access? or Who has access? please.

The key part at the duplicate is: "Since one need not know (and is conventionally assumed not to know) the answer to one's question, interrogative who, what, and which subjects can be assumed to agree with singular verbs in the question." Also: the best way to talk about your question is in the comment section. Editing your question is great for adding extra context or clearing up anything that was confusing.

To boil that down further: Singular is best especially when context hasn't yet established a plural (and sometimes even when it has).

@AndyBonner the best way to talk about your question is in the comment section. Editing your question is great for adding extra context or clearing up anything that was confusing No sir, Your post has been associated with a similar question. If that question doesn’t answer your issue, edit your question to highlight the difference between the associated question and yours. I was acting in accordance with rules of this website AND my answer is still not answered which is Who has access to data? or Who have access to data? we're supposed to get answers here not a bossy debate.

Sorry, I thought I had been clear. It's "who has."

I've already answered:  [a] (1) 'Who has access to the data?' and  (2) 'Who have access to the data?' are both grammatical. But you don't add this reasonable context (and singular they is a possibility with the minimal context provided). // Expanding, if the questioner knows that there is more than one correct answer, they may prefer (2), but the distributive singular usage (an in-house search will explain) allows (1) also. 'Dear Reader, I married him.'/ If the questioner is 'sure' that there is only one correct answer, they may well opt for (1), but again (2) is not unacceptable. ...

They may be mistaken, and it's better to aim for completeness. //// Note that no one would say "Who are he?" or "Who is they?"  So interrogative 'who' is not restricted to one verb form or the other. But with more complicated sentences, as stated, there arises a sophisticated level of choice.
